# Python: Reading input when finished typing

Tags: python

I am writing a python script which is going to take use of input from a barcode scanner. As it stands, the barcode scanner acts as a keyboard, writing the scanned code into the console (such a code may for ex. be: 123456789). Is there a way to automatically read the inputted code when the scanner is finished writing? Right now the user has to press enter any time a code is scanned. Are there any existing libraries for barcode scanners that i have yet to come accross?

Comment: Normally the barcode scanner can be configured to send the `enter` key after the code. Check its manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the input with `raw_input` will not work because it waits for the user hitting the return button. However, `sys.stdin.read()` reads single characters from the standard input. Use this function and check if the characters that were already entered are as many as you expect.

Information about read(): https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=read#file.read. sys.stdin works like a file.